# RSA::PublicKey Load function segfaults ART (Android Runtime)

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault, android-5.0-lollipop, crypto++

We have implemented a small wrapper for Cryptopp to exchange keys between iOS and Android(JNI). Shared code works on iOS and pre-ART android devices. Supposedly ART and its garbage collector is a lot stricter now.

It might be important to point out that set private key function succeeds on both Dalvik and ART runtimes.

Code:
--> setting public key :

```
jboolean *isCopy;
//get bytes from jbytearray
jbyte* ba = (jbyte *)env->GetByteArrayElements( byteArray, isCopy);

//load bytearray to crypto bytequeue
ByteQueue queue2;

queue2.Put2((byte*)ba, 1000, 0, true);

//build public key
AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
publicKey.Load(*queue2);  //<-------- CRASH
```

--> setting private key

```
jboolean *isCopy;
jbyte* ba = (jbyte *)env->GetByteArrayElements( byteArray, isCopy);

//load bytearray to bytequeue
ByteQueue queue2;
queue2.Put2((byte*)ba, 3072, 0, true);

//fill up the key
RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.Load(queue2);
```

Stack trace:

```
 backtrace:
     #00 pc 00027e6c  <project_name>/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so
     #01 pc 00027e79  <project_name>/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so
     #02 pc 00027efb  <project_name>/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so (std::terminate()+6)
     #03 pc 000273d3  <project_name>/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so
     #04 pc 000268c9  <project_name>/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so
     #05 pc 0002698b  <project_name>/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so (__cxa_throw+34)
     #06 pc 001b3ce4  <project_name>/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so (CryptoPP::BERDecodeError()+128)
     #07 pc 001b1598  <project_name>/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so (CryptoPP::BERGeneralDecoder::Init(unsigned char)+56)
     #08 pc 001b1638  <project_name>/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so (CryptoPP::BERGeneralDecoder::BERGeneralDecoder(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned char)+104)
     #09 pc 0027697c  <project_name>/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so (CryptoPP::Integer::BERDecode(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&)+20)
     #10 pc 002aec7c  <project_name>/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so (CryptoPP::RSAFunction::BERDecodePublicKey(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, bool, unsigned int)+64)
     #11 pc 001b20e0  <project_name>/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so (CryptoPP::X509PublicKey::BERDecode(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&)+264)
     #12 pc 00014a0b  <project_name>/lib/arm/libsecurity.so (CryptoPP::ASN1CryptoMaterial<CryptoPP::PublicKey>::Load(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&)+6)
```

Might be worth mentioning that new (mostly) Google devices (Nexus 4,5,7) use ART by default now.

Please advice!

Comment: How did you make out on this?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> jbyte* ba = (jbyte *)env->GetByteArrayElements( byteArray, isCopy);
> ByteQueue queue; 
> queue.Put((byte*)ba, 1000, 0, true);
> ...
> ```

And:

> ```
> ByteQueue queue;
> queue.Put((byte*)ba, 3072, 0, true);
> ...
> ```

That is not correct. You can't hardcode the size when the keys are usually a couple hundred bytes.

Here's the code I use to work with the `jbyteArray`:

```
if(env && ba)
{
    ReadByteBuffer buffer(env, ba);

    const byte* _arr = buffer.GetByteArray();
    size_t _len = buffer.GetArrayLen();

    ByteQueue queue;
    queue.Put(_arr, _len);
    ...
}
```

And you should wrap it in a `try/catch` while catching a `BERDecodeErr` in case its not well formed. It seems to be another problem you are having. See [BERDecodeErr Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_b_e_r_decode_err.html).

---

This is not quite correct either (notice the pointer dereference for a stack-based `ByteQueue`):

```
ByteQueue queue2;
...
publicKey.Load(*queue2);
```

I'm going to write that discrepancy off, but you should ensure the code you are posting is representative of what you are doing.

---

> Might be worth mentioning that new (mostly) Google devices (Nexus 4,5,7) use ART by default now.

I have a Nexus 5 for testing, and Crypto++ runs fine :)

---

Here's the class I use for `ReadByteBuffer`. It handles the release in the destructor.

```
class ReadByteBuffer
{
public:
    explicit ReadByteBuffer(JNIEnv*& env, jbyteArray& barr)
    : m_env(env), m_arr(barr), m_ptr(NULL), m_len(0)
    {
        if(m_env && m_arr)
        {
            m_ptr = m_env->GetByteArrayElements(m_arr, NULL);
            m_len = m_env->GetArrayLength(m_arr);
        }
    }

    ~ReadByteBuffer()
    {
        if(m_env && m_arr)
        {
            m_env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(m_arr, m_ptr, JNI_ABORT);
        }
    }

    const byte* GetByteArray() const {
        return (const byte*) m_ptr;
    }

    size_t GetArrayLen() const {
        if(m_len < 0)
            return 0;
        return (size_t) m_len;
    }

private:
    JNIEnv*& m_env;
    jbyteArray& m_arr;

    jbyte* m_ptr;
    jint m_len;
};
```

And here's the class I use for writing. Like its counterpart, `WriteByteBuffer` handles the commit and the release in the destructor.

```
class WriteByteBuffer
{
public:
    explicit WriteByteBuffer(JNIEnv*& env, jbyteArray& barr)
    : m_env(env), m_arr(barr), m_ptr(NULL), m_len(0)
    {
        if(m_env && m_arr)
        {
            m_ptr = m_env->GetByteArrayElements(m_arr, NULL);
            m_len = m_env->GetArrayLength(m_arr);
        }
    }

    ~WriteByteBuffer()
    {
        if(m_env && m_arr)
        {
            m_env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(m_arr, m_ptr, 0);
        }
    }

    byte* GetByteArray() const {
        return (byte*) m_ptr;
    }

    size_t GetArrayLen() const {
        if(m_len < 0)
            return 0;
        return (size_t) m_len;
    }

private:
    JNIEnv*& m_env;
    jbyteArray& m_arr;

    jbyte* m_ptr;
    jint m_len;
};
```